# Is it correct use of an inversion?

Tags: grammar

> It is more probable for the experts to makes contribution than is for the beginners in a field.

It seems not OK, please help me.

Comment: the sentence is weird. I'm struggling what exactly it means! :)

Comment: I'm not sure where the inversion is but I would say: *It is more probable that the experts will make a contribution in this field than that the beginners will.* It is a bit more bulky, but the meaning is clearer (at least to me). If you want to stick to the original construction consider two things: infinitive (to make) is different from 3rd person sg. (makes); the part after *than* is a clause and needs a subject (it). Subject can be omitted rarely, but not here.

Comment: It's more probable for experts to make contribution in a field than it's  for beginners.

Comment: @Khan - I think that should either be: "...to make a contribution..." or: "to make contributions..." Moreover, I would strongly recommend **against** using the second "it's": *It's more probable for experts to make contributions in a field than it is for beginners.*

Comment: J.R. you are right. It should be contributions/a contribution. I agree the second it's  seems unnecessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple, short and understandable I'd say:

> It is more likely an expert will contribute than a beginner.

or if you want to add "in a field":

> It is more likely an expert in a field will contribute than a beginner.